# get 500 internal server error after install checklist plugins on redmine

Tags: redmine-plugins

I've just installed checklist plugin on my redmine, but now I can't create new issues or view the existing issues detail.

Here is the error message on my production log:

```
Started GET "/issues/579" for 103.83.94.10 at 2018-11-15 09:42:38 +0700
Processing by IssuesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"579"}
Current user: periyanto (id=12)
Rendering issues/show.html.erb within layouts/base
Rendered issues/_action_menu.html.erb (5.1ms)
Rendered attachments/_links.html.erb (6.3ms)
Rendered plugins/redmine_checklists/app/views/issues/_checklist.html.erb (1.7ms)
Rendered issues/show.html.erb within layouts/base (46.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 136ms (ActiveRecord: 29.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Issue::Checklist):
1: <% if !@issue.blank? && @issue.checklists.any? && User.current.allowed_to?(:view_checklists, @project) %>
2: <hr />
3: <div id="checklist">
4:
```

Redmine version                3.4.2.devel.16963
Ruby version                   2.3.4-p301
Rails version                  5.1.2
redmine_checklists             3.1.11

Need the advice to solve this problem.

Comment: Have backed out, to confirm the change is the cause of the error (HTTP 500) ?

Comment: yes, if i remove this plugins everything back normally

Comment: Yeah, thats a pretty serious error. Is there a dedicated community, that supports install/config?